# javascript to calculate average from loop output

Tags: javascript, arrays, average

I would like to get rid of the "undefined" and also average the priceList array values that are output to the console. I apply this code in the Chrome console using the https://experts.shopify.com/designers web page. Thank you for your help!

```
//selects the all of the designer cards
var experts = document.querySelectorAll('.expert-card__content');

//This tells us how many designer cards there are
var expertsQty = experts.length;
var expertContent =document.getElementsByClassName("expert-list-summary txt--minor");

//expertContent[0].innerText
var i;
var priceMedian;
var prices;
var priceList = 0;

for(i=0; i<experts.length; i++){

    //Grabs the content 
    var str = expertContent[i].innerText;

    //This determines the position of the last $ in the text
    var strPosition = expertContent[i].innerText.lastIndexOf("$");

    //This goes to the position of the $ and shows the 1 word after it.
    var expertPrice= str.substring(strPosition + 1);

    //iterate through expert content
    parseInt(expertPrice);
    parseInt(prices);
    priceList = prices += expertPrice;
    }
```

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: `parseInt` takes a string and return a number! it should be used like this: 

`var number = parseInt("45");`!

Comment: Plus the numbers on the website are in this format `3,456` which is not a valid number!

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the website in the link you provided. Here is a way to calculate the average:

```
// get the second <p>s of inside the <div>s with the classes expert-list-summary and txt--minor
var experts = document.querySelectorAll(".expert-list-summary.txt--minor p:nth-child(2)");

var qty = experts.length;                          // the quantity is the cound of those p elements
var prices = 0;                                    // prices must be initialized to 0 (otherwise you get an average of NaN)

for(var i = 0; i < experts.length; i++) {
    var str = experts[i].textContent;              // get the text content of that p element
    str = str.replace(/,/g, '');                   // remove commas as they're not valid in numbers
    var price = parseInt(str.match(/\$(\d+)/)[1]); // use a rgular expression to retrieve the number it's clearer (match any number after the dollar sign, read more about regular expressions)
    prices += price;                               // add this price to the prices (accumulate the prices)
}

var average = prices / qty;                        // the average is the sum of prices divided by the quantity
```